Why do people seem to think less effectively when being helped or watched?
I've noticed a recurring behavior in various technical settings conducted over Zoom, where screen sharing seems to induce a more passive cognitive state among participants. Whether in debugging sessions, classroom code walkthroughs, or virtual hackathons, participants often defer to the screen sharer, becoming observers rather than active contributors.

Are there any studies or observations that support a decrease in cognitive engagement during screen sharing in remote settings like Zoom?
What theories might explain why participants tend to take a passive role, potentially limiting their learning and engagement?

Insights into the psychological dynamics of screen sharing, particularly theories like "social loafing" or "reactivity," would be highly appreciated.
